# Java Message logging Web Application

Tags: java, logging, server-side

My Apache Tomcat Server is getting periodic updates from a Java based client Application, At the moment the scenario is just one client and talking to the server.
I want to log the messages from the client onto the server with time-stamp what kind of framework will help me in achieving this?

Comment: What are exactly these messages? What do they contain? Are they text based? What do you mean exactly by "I want to log the messages [...] with time-stamp"? Do you want to store the messages durably? Do you just want to write their content in a text file? Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I am just receiving 3 to 4 real time values from my java client, these are in the query string of the HTTP request. I would want a way to save or log these values and then do some processing on the server like show graphs/charts using this data.

Comment: Do you mean 1) processing and generating a web page with some graphs/charts or 2) using a tool like Excel to process the written values?

Comment: Processing and generating a web page with the said items...

Comment: Ok. Then write your messages to a database. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: The OP goal was actually pretty unclear and I'm modifying my answer after some clarifications.

<strike>Well, I'm not sure, but maybe a logging framework will suit your needs. If so, have a look at:</strike>

- [Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/): The most famous logging framework, widely used.
- [Java Logging](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/util/logging/overview.html) aka `java.util.logging`: didn't succeed to replace Log4J.
- [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/): "*Logback is intended as a successor to the popular log4j project. It was designed, in addition to many individual contributors, by Ceki Gülcü, the founder of log4j*".
- [SL4J](http://www.slf4j.org/): A "*Simple Logging Facade for Java serves as a simple facade or abstraction for various logging frameworks, e.g. java.util.logging, log4j and logback, allowing the end user to plug in the desired logging framework at deployment time*".

And pick one of them (I'd use Log4J or Logback).

To save your messages for later processing from the webapp (e.g. generating a web page with some graphs/charts), the best approach is to use a database. Just read/write them from/to a simple table with a timestamp column.

If you are not really familiar with Java, JDBC, persistence, connection pooling, datasource, etc, I'd suggest to use the [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/about) framework as it will hide most of the complexity. For the database part, have a look at the [Chapter 11. Data access using JDBC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jdbc.html) from the Spring documentation. Pay a special attention to the `JdbcTemplate` or the `SimpleJdbcTemplate`, they should allow you to get the job done.

Comment: I wouldn't really know!...Frankly I haven't much experience working on server side, so any help would be great!!

Comment: A logging framework is a tool that helps programmers to output log statements to a variety of output targets. The Log4J FAQ may help you to understand what a logging framework is about http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html

Answer (score 1):

Create a special JSP page for accepting log entries, and invoke it with

http://..... foo.jsp?l=the%20stuff%to%log  (i.e. URL encoded)

You then just need to pick out the "l" parameter and do with it what you need to do.  An initial implementation could be invoking the log(String s) method in the servlet context.